# Use Principle of Mathematical Induction to show that for all $n\:\in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n=2^{n+2}\cdot 5^{2n+1}+3^{n+2}\cdot 2^{2n+1}$ is divisible by 19

Tags: induction

Here's what I did:

**Base Case: $n = 1$**, $2^3*5^3+3^3*2^3$ = $1216$ = $19(64)$

**Induction Hypothesis (IH):** $a_k=2^{k+2}\cdot 5^{2k+1}+3^{k+2}\cdot 2^{2k+1}$ for some $k\:\in \mathbb{N}$.

**Inductive Step:** $a_{k+1}=2^{\left(k+1\right)+2}\cdot \:5^{2\left(k+1\right)+1}+3^{\left(k+1\right)+2}\cdot \:2^{2\left(k+1\right)+1}$

$a_{k+1}=2^{\left(k+2\right)}\cdot 2\cdot \:5^{2k+1}\cdot 5^2+3^{k+2}\cdot 3\cdot \:2^{2k+1}\cdot 2^2$

$a_{k+1}=2^{k+2}\:\cdot 5^{2k+1}\cdot 50+3^{k+2}\cdot 2^{2k+1}\cdot 12$

How do I prove that the latter statement is divisible by 19?

(I've tried to set up the equation in a way where I know that $2^{k+2}\:\cdot 5^{2k+1}$ and $3^{k+2}\cdot 2^{2k+1}$ is divisible by 19. I'm not sure about the 50 and the 12.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there! Hint for the finish:
$$
2^{k+2}\cdot 5^{2k+1}\cdot 50+3^{k+2}\cdot 2^{2k+1}\cdot 12\\
= 12\left(2^{k+2}\cdot 5^{2k+1}+3^{k+2}\cdot 2^{2k+1}\right) + 38\left(2^{k+2}\cdot 5^{2k+1}\right)
$$

Comment: Just curious, is there a direct proof strategy for this claim?

Comment: @AlanAbraham Rewrite $a_n = 20 \cdot 50^n + 18 \cdot 12^n$. Modulo $19$, this becomes $1 \cdot 12^n + (-1) \cdot 12^n = 0$.

Comment: I get that the latter part of the equation is divisible by 19 because 19(2) = 38. Still not sure about the first part...

Comment: @Yaya123 This is an induction proof. What was the induction hypothesis?

Comment: @AlanAbraham Use the induction hypothesis as much as possible until the expression becomes strictly simpler. Then look at what you have left.

Comment: By IH, $a_k=2^{k+2}\cdot 5^{2k+1}+3^{k+2}\cdot 2^{2k+1}$ for some $k\:\in \mathbb{N}$ is divisible by 19 hence the first part is also divisible by 19

Comment: @Arthur I was just wondering since I had seen a similar problem and was wondering if there was any reason why it was intuitively true.

Comment: @AlanAbraham You mean something other than an induction proof like this?